# php script for uploading files to a remote server

Tags: php

I'm am completely new to PHP scripting so these questions I have are probably going to be silly simplistic ones, so please forgive me.

Right now I have code that I'm wanting to use to send files to set folder in my server.

My code looks like this:

```
    <?

$_SESSION['directory'] = $_POST['directory'];
$uploaddir = './'.$_GET["dir"];
$file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

print_r($_FILES);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http://ipaddress/images/{$file}/";
}
else
{
    echo "Didn't Work!!!!";
}
```

?>

My URL call for this in my code looks like this:

```
http://server.foo.com/folder/uploadToDirectory.php?dir=selected_folder
```

However when I run my code, the file only gets sent to the root of the directory like it would if I make this call:

```
http://server.foo.com/folder/uploadToDirectory.php
```

Can anyone see the reason as to why that is happening?

Following that if I want to save a file in a directory I need a separate script from that if I want to upload it to the root of my server. How would I go combing my two scripts into one, and what calls would I need to make if I'm already using them like I've shown.

My other script looks like this:

```
<?

    $file = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

    print_r($_FILES);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
            echo "http://ipaddress/images/{$file}/";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Didn't Work!!!!";
    }

?>
```

Please note, I know this is a horrible way of doing things. I know that. But this is code that only I am going to be using. No end client will see this. So please, if you could help with the code I have provided I would be truly grateful.

Comment: You have to use ftp_connect,ftp_login...etc and all its related functions in order to make this to work.

Comment: My server doesn't make use of FTP and I have no way of adding it in. My file upload is dealt with by these scripts I deal with in C#. Would you like me to put up my C# call?

Comment: You can make the call of your php file anywhere, even into some android app. The ideea is that when your php(server1) file is called, the script needs to connect to server 2 using ftp credentials (remote).After login, you handle with the moving of files that needs to be "uploaded". You cannot use move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"htt p://192.168.0.5/images/"); ftp_connect is a function!!no need to add  it.You just use it.

Comment: But i am using the above scripts to send a file to my server. It works fine and I don't need to use FTP

Comment: In the 2'nd scritp you don't have the $uploaddir = './'.$_GET["dir"]; . To select the directory the url must contain ....?dir=your_directory. $_GET["dir"] will take the value of the "dir" from url. Make sense?

Comment: Yes but in my first script I do have that part but my file and it still doesn't upload it to the correct directory. It only sends it to the root.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36993/discussion-between-drk-alien-and-n0xus)

Comment: @N0xus *"I'm am completely new to PHP scripting"* Then you might not know that when using sessions, `session_start();` needs to be in all your files and usually as your first line after your opening PHP tag; unless you do know and haven't made a mention about it. This could be "one" of the problems. Also you need short tags to be "ON" if you're to use just `<?` instead of `<?php`

Comment: @N0xus Another thing is that you're mixing `$_POST` with `$_GET`, which usually don't work out too well with each other, unless there's a particular reason for doing so. They're usually both/all `$_POST` or `$_GET`. Regarding `$uploaddir = './'.$_GET["dir"];` how is `$_GET["dir"];` being defined? You may be better off using `$uploaddir = 'uploads/';` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least, I think you need the directory separator between the `$uploaddir` and `$uploadfile` so try changing:

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;
```

to

```
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . '/' . $file;
```

Also make sure to sanitize `$uploaddir` because something like `../../some_dir` may let me upload to arbitrary directories.  And uploading of a file with a .php extension would allow me to upload PHP code to your server and run it, so be advised of some of these issues.